# Intuitive Active / Idle / Off status button

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns, visual-cues

I have a requirement to visually show the three status of Active / Idle / Off status for devices.  I somehow convinced with switch design as you can see in the below illusion,

[image]

not fully satisfied as I need to show other one interstate of "Idle" apart from Active / Inactive or On / Off.  Rather than showing as text or drop down UI, wanna show this as single visual representation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Try these answers](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83549/is-required-validation-possible-on-a-switch-toggle-control/83550#83550) - not the same question but they will work for this.

Comment: Even though this one is good option, doesn't it leads to confusion when users seeing this first time?

Comment: I mocked it up just to see, I think it'll depend on the context of the toggle: http://jsfiddle.net/b0ehf0mf/

Comment: Ah I see now you want to be able to return to that middle state not just have it as a default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wan't to have a selector with 3 states I wouldn't use a toggle, a toggle button is good if there is only two states (or two plus a default like I tried to show in comments) but if you want to introduce a third state there becomes issues such as which state to switch to on click, and how to properly show what each state represents.

**The slider:**

[image]

Sliders allow you to have multiple states, allows you to clearly label each state to avoid confusion, and lets you toggle to whichever state you want in a single swipe.

**The segmented control:**

[image]

Gives all the benefits of a slider without the sliding. Easily toggle between multiple states in a single click.

Comment: Yes, this segmented control is a great approach for selecting between multiple states in a single click. Check out this article which highlights some research around it, and also some other great alternatives to a drop-down: http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1950

Comment: @ThomasAdcock ah segmented control that's the word I was looking for thanks, and good article.